# Mustache conflict at release build

Tags: erlang, rebar

I use wooga's fork of mustache.erl (https://github.com/wooga/mustache.erl) in my project. And when I try to create release I get an error because rebar uses this mustache.beam file instead of a file included in its source.
What should I do to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Issue on this problem: https://github.com/rebar/rebar/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not in `rebar` but is that some app in release tool search path contains the `mustache.erl` file as you release does.
Usually `rel.config` file contains `{lib_dirs, ["../.."]}` that force release tool search libs (apps) up your release directory. See example below. To fix it, move your release directory dipper (for example -> you_release/you_release) or move app that contains the same file (mustache.erl) to other place.

```
├── your_release_directory
│   ├── deps
│   │   └── mustache
│   │       ├── ebin
│   │       │   ├── mustache.app
│   │       │   └── mustache.beam
│   │       └── src
│   │           ├── mustache.app.src
│   │           └── mustache.erl
│   ├── ebin
│   │   └── mustache.beam
├── rebar (or any other app contains mustache.erl)
│   ├── ebin
│   │   └── mustache.beam
│   ├── src
│   │   └── mustache.erl
```